# Intellij Github Integration gives me a different account

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ IDE. I am trying to integrate Git/GitHub with the IDE. I am basically trying to commit and push my code to my personal GitHub. The problem is that an unknown GitHub account is already linked to my IDE and I don't know how to delete it.

When I go to `VCS -> Import into version control -> Share project on GitHub`it shows the unknown GitHub account.
Moreover, the account does exist in the version control either (`CTRL + ALT + S`).
Here, I deleted my account that I previously had and recreated it. This did not work.
Moreover, I also used the command line to verify `git config user.name and user.email`. This gave me the correct information relating to myself.

This issue arose when I downloaded a java project for a code test.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/faGlp.png

Comment: Try deleting the account here: File | Settings | Version Control | GitHub

Comment: Thats what i did

Comment: Where exactly doe the "unknown GitHub account" is shown? Could you please provide more details - e.g. screenshots - to clarify the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub account and `git config user.name` are not in fact related. Setting in git config defines the author of commits but does not affect authentication to GitHub. The GitHub account in IDE Setting, on the contrary, affects the only authentication to GitHub, but does not define authors.

IntelliJ relies on git, so all the commit author things are on the git side. The account one enters in the [IDE settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/github.html) is only used for authentication to GitHub. This is the only account linked to the IDE. Deleting an entry in Settings would stop IDE from using this account anywhere.

On the other hand, git client might be using its own [credential-helpers](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) to help with authentication, and if some account is saved in the helper, it might produce unexpected behavior.